# Insert into with MEMO data type doesn't work in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert with `select` statement, but I get the error saying that I have `syntax error` with `insert into` statement.

```
insert into S2T_BL(note)
SELECT S2T.[work]
FROM S2T;
```

Just select works fine itself:

```
SELECT S2T.[work]
FROM S2T;
```

Even trying `insert` without that column works fine, where `desc` is not memo data type:

```
    insert into S2T_BL(desc)
    SELECT S2T.[desc]
    FROM S2T;
```

`S2T.[work]` and `S2T_BL.note` are both MEMO data type, so  I believe problem related with data type. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get an error with this one? `INSERT INTO S2T_BL([note]) SELECT S2T.[work] FROM S2T;`  If so, is it the same or a different error?

Comment: Wow, thank you  a lot @HansUp - this problem is really weird))

Comment: @HansUp you can post it as an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is actually not due to Memo datatype.  Rather the problem is because `note` is a [Jet reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#N).

I created *S2T_BL* and *S2T* tables with *note* and *work* Memo fields.  Then enclosing the name *note* in square brackets allowed this query to execute without error:

```sql
INSERT INTO S2T_BL([note]) SELECT S2T.[work] FROM S2T;
```

Without the square brackets ... ie `INSERT INTO S2T_BL(note) SELECT S2T.[work] FROM S2T` ... I got a syntax error as you reported.

Reserved words are a common cause of Access query problems, so it's best to avoid them if possible.  When you can't avoid them, at least beware of them so you can take precautions.  In case you're unsure which words are officially reserved or otherwise problematic, you can use Allen Browne's [Database Issue Checker Utility](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html) to examine your database.  In addition to reserved/problem names, it can also warn you about other issues which may complicate your Access development.